# Serialising and deserialising a JSON object returned by an ASP.Net web service

Tags: asp.net, json, serialization

I have a simple ASP.Net web service / script method that returns a JSON object which is then modified and send back to the page during post back - I need to be able to deserialise this object:

```
public class MyWebPage : Page
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod]
    public static MyClass MyWebMethod()
    {
        // Example implementation of my web method
        return new MyClass() 
        {
            MyString = "Hello World",
            MyInt = 42,
        };
    }

    protected void myButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // I need to replace this with some real code
        MyClass obj = JSONDeserialise(this.myHiddenField.Value);
    }
}

// Note that MyClass is contained within a different assembly
[Serializable]
public class MyClass : IXmlSerializable, ISerializable
{
    public string MyString { get; set; }
    public int MyInt { get; set; }
    // IXmlSerializable and ISerializable implementations not shown
}
```

I can make changes to both the web method `MyWebMethod`, and also to a certain extent  `MyClass`, however `MyClass` needs to implemnt both `IXmlSerializable` and `ISerializable`, and is contained within a separate assembly - I mention this because these have caused problems for me so far.

How can I do this? (either using standard .Net types or using something like JSON.Net)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScriptSerializer class from System.Web.Extensions to deserialize JSON string. For example, the following code converts hash into .NET dictionary object:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dict = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string,int>>("{ a: 1, b: 2 }");
            Console.WriteLine(dict["a"]);
            Console.WriteLine(dict["b"]);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Code output is:

```
1
2
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScriptSerializer is the class that static page methods use to serialize their responses, so it's also what's appropriate for deserializing that particular JSON:

```
protected void myButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string json = myHiddleField.Value;

    MyClass obj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<MyClass>(json);
}
```